# Есть ли альтернативы методу complete_phone_login в MadelineProto?

Tags: php, telegram, madelineproto, mtproto

Как финальный результат мне нужно получить [auth.Authorization](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/types/auth_Authorization.html).

Раньше был метод где можно было передать `phone_code_hash` и `phone_code` и всё работало. А щас через `complete_phone_login` не понятно какой из пользователей авторизуеться (использую [`Amp`](https://github.com/amphp/http-server) сервер).

Какой метод щас можно использовать чтобы по `phone`, `phone_code` и `phone_code_hash` авторизоваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел:

```
$mtproto->method_call(
    'auth.signIn',
    [
        'phone_number' => $phone['phone_number'],
        'phone_code_hash' => $phone['phone_code_hash'],
        'phone_code' => $args['code']
    ],
    ['datacenter' => 2]
);
```